# How to run Liquibase migrations at startup in dropwizard projects?

Tags: java, liquibase, dropwizard

I'm using dropwizard-migrations library. The documented method is to run the migration command after jar is built.

I'm wondering if there is any standard way that this can be done in the application initialization/after the startup.

Are there any classes that can invoke to make this happen at startup?

Comment: What version of Dropwizard are you using?

Comment: @htshame dropwizard 1.3.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run migrations programmatically in Dropwizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579607/run-migrations-programmatically-in-dropwizard)